# Openoffice access files on NFS extremely slow and can not save file

Tags: networking, openoffice, libreoffice, nfs, sshfs

I am using a Debian 7 box. I have an NFS network drive mounted on my "/mnt/drive_R". Everything works fine except Apache openoffice 4.1 and LibreOffice 3.5, yes I tried both version of openoffice.

I can use openoffice (calc, impress, writer) on a sshfs mounted drive without problem. But whenever I try to open a file (calc, impress, writer) from my NFS drive (/mnt/drive_R), it takes long time to load. And when try to same a file to /mnt/drive_R, after a long time freeze, openoffice popup message saying: "Error saving the document Untitled2: Error during shared access to /mnt/drive_R/temp/test_ss.ods". After that, I find a 0 byte file test_ss.ods under the target directory. My NFS drive has 1TB free spaces.

Comment: Are you having the same problems with any other program and commands on the NFS volume?  More precisely, can you write to a file on your NFS mount from the shell, did you do command line copy tests with `dd` to compare the speed the actual connection speed?

Comment: yes, everything else works just fine. I have other git repositories on NFS volume. On the NFS volume, I edit program using vim, edit paper, commit change and checkout etc. Only Openoffice has trouble with the NFS volume.

Comment: I can understand that it could go slowly depending on the approach taken to access the file's content, but nothing should stop one from writing completely while the others can.

Comment: Could that same file be accessed by another computer at the same time?

Comment: Not possible, I even tried to create a new document from openoffice and try "save as..." to save it into a new file on NFS volume. It gives me the error I mentioned in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

After some more research I finally confirmed this link work around my problem
[answer to my question](http://forum.qnap.com/viewtopic.php?t=33959)

So it's my NAS has the NFS bug, whilst only OO tries to do file lock in my case.